# Gatsby JSS "Flicker" on page load

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering, serverside-javascript, jss

There is a "flicker" of unstyled content on page load of my Gatbsy site. It's probably most helpful to look at the current deploy preview here https://happy-mahavira-5cd669.netlify.com/.

My research up to this point has led me to the gatsby-config.js file as the source of the problem. This is what that file currently looks like:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Dillon Morris - UI Designer & Developer',
    author: 'Dillon Morris',
    siteUrl: 'www.dillonmorris.me',
    description: 'Dillon is a UI/UX Developer & Designer in Phoenix, AZ',
  },
  plugins: [
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet,
    {
      resolve: gatsby-plugin-jss,
      options: {},
    },
    {
      resolve: gatsby-source-filesystem,
      options: {
        name: src,
        path: ${__dirname}/src/,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: gatsby-transformer-remark,
      options: {
        plugins: [gatsby-remark-prismjs],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: gatsby-plugin-manifest,
      options: {
        name: 'Dillon Morris UI/UX Designer & Developer',
        short_name: 'Dillon',
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: '#663399',
        theme_color: '#663399',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/logo.png', // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    gatsby-plugin-offline,
    'gatsby-plugin-netlify',
  ],
}
```

I've also tried having `gatsby-plugin-jss` listed plainly in the plugins array (just like `gatsyby-plugin-react-helmet`) as opposed to the object with resolve and options properties, no luck.

That's the extent of troubleshooting I've been able to muster on my own, I know no other ways of diagnosing or fixing this problem. This problem is not happening locally in development mode, only once built and deployed to Netlify.

Feel free to pull down the code and poke around if you feel so inclined. 
https://github.com/dillonmorris91/portfoliodm.

Thank you Stack Overflow community ❤️

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Same issue. No frameworks just react components using sass for styling deployed to netlify. Any solution?

Comment: Hi! Did you end up finding the solution? I'm having the same problem on my page:

https://playmirage.netlify.app/character-sheet

Please let me know if you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

The styles for your home page need to be declared before your main CSS

You could use: 
[gatsby-plugin-global-styles](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-global-styles/?=styles-)

It enables you to reorder your style tags in the header. I put mine as high as possible and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see your site does not have the JSS plugin installed (currently on GH). So the first thing I would try:

1. `npm i --save gatsby-plugin-jss`
2. add `"gatsby-plugin-jss"` to the `plugins: [...]` array in the `gatsby-config.js` file

(a `gatsby clean` couldn't hurt after all this, but it's good to go)

Answer (score -2):

I don't use gatsby yet, from JSS standpoint the flicker may come if you remove critical CSS before you render the components with CSS.